# Use list of csr_matrix to train SGDClassifier

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy

I've a list `X_train` (>20000 elements) with each element being a sparse scipy `csr_matrix` created by `HashingVectorizer.transform()`.

My `HashingVectorizer.transform()` does line by line transformation of the input file and appends it to the list X_train.

I'm trying to train a `SGDClassifier` using X_train but I get the error:

`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`.

How can I train the SGDClassifier without having to do a CPU or memory intensive operation?

Comment: The classifier is probably trying to turn the list into an array, e.g. `np.asarray(X_train)`.  What's the shape of the matrix elements?.  Can the list be turned into one large sparse matrix with `sparse.vstack`?

Comment: When you ask about an error like this you should, to be polite, provide information about where it occurred.  That is a stack trace, and if possible more information about the suspected problem variables.

Comment: your method works! thank you! and thanks for the heads up, I'll remember to include the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list of sparse matrices, and ways of turning that into an array or sparse matrix (or not):

```
In [916]: alist=[sparse.random(1,10,.2, format='csr') for _ in range(3)]
In [917]: alist
Out[917]: 
[<1x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>]
```

making a proper sparse matrix (2d):

```
In [918]: sparse.vstack(alist)
Out[918]: 
<3x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

object array of matrices - bad

```
In [919]: np.array(alist)
Out[919]: 
array([ <1x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       <1x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       <1x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>], dtype=object)
```

Trying to make a float array - your error

```
In [920]: np.array(alist, float)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-920-52d4689fa7b3> in <module>()
----> 1 np.array(alist, float)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```