# Sklearn DBscan Cannot Fit CSR Sparse Data

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I have some sparse data which I transform into **CSR sparse vector**:

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

num_news = indexed.agg(max(indexed["newsIndex"])).take(1)[0][0] + 1  # maximum index of the news in the data

def get_matrix(news):
    row = [0 for i in news]
    data = [1 for i in news]
    return coo_matrix((data, (row,news)), shape=(1, num_news)).tocsr()

d['feature'] = d['newsArr'].apply(get_matrix)
```

Then, I show it by using `pd.head`:

```
uuid    newsArr     feature
0   014324000050581     [300.0, 274.0]  (0, 274)\t1\n (0, 300)\t1
1   014379002854034     [3539.0, 1720.0, 402.0, 1787.0, 2854.0, 2500.0...   (0, 402)\t1\n (0, 492)\t1\n (0, 493)\t1\n ...
2   014379004874618     [346.0]     (0, 346)\t1
3   014379004904357     [592.0, 1586.0, 20.0, 4165.0, 19.0, 165.0, 12.0]    (0, 12)\t1\n (0, 19)\t1\n (0, 20)\t1\n (0...
4   014379004920072     [1658.0, 283.0, 7.0, 492.0]     (0, 7)\t1\n (0, 283)\t1\n (0, 492)\t1\n (...
```

The output of `d['feature'][:1].tolist()` is the following:

```
[<1x93315 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>]
```

Then I want to use DBscan:

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

db = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples=10).fit_predict(d['feature'])
```

However, I receive the following error:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I believe it is not reasonable since my vector is `1*num_news`. Then I try to use `tolist()`:

```
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples=10).fit_predict(d['feature'].tolist())
```

The following error pops up:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ <1x93315 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
 <1x93315 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 19 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
 <1x93315 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
 ...,
 <1x93315 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
 <1x93315 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
 <1x93315 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 15 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

I know that `sklearn` can use **CSR sparse matrix** as input, how can I do that ?

Comment: You aren't giving it a sparse matrix.  In the second case you give it a list of matrices.  The error arises when it tries to turn that list into an array.

Comment: A similar problem using a list of sparse matrices: [Use list of csr_matrix to train SGDClassifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45249885/use-list-of-csr-matrix-to-train-sgdclassifier)

Comment: yes you are right, thank you very much~